# Firebase Authentication Not successfull

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made an Android project and registered application on Firebase now i am not getting the messege from Firebase i have already put the Jason file in the app folder
also i have enable the phone authentication in Firebase also
please help me with the mistake.

ERROR

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:    
com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@a1576ff
D/vrification failes: asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd`
```

MY CODE

```
 findViewById(R.id.bt1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendVerificationCode();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.bt2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verifySignInCode();
        }
    });
}
private void verifySignInCode(){

    String code=et2.getText().toString().trim();
    PhoneAuthCredential credential=PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codesent,code);
    signInWithAuthCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential){
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new   
    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
       if(task.isSuccessful()){
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"login success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       } else{
            if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"login fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
       }
        }
    });
}
private void sendVerificationCode(){
    String phone=et1.getText().toString().trim();
    if(phone.isEmpty()){
        et1.setError("required");
        et1.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(phone.length()<10){
        et1.setError("valid");
        et1.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
          phone,
          60,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS,
          this,
          mCallbacks);
}
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks=new                
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
       Log.d("vrification failed","asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken){
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        codesent=s;
        Log.d("verification started","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    }
  };
}`
```

Can Anyone tell me what is the mistake weather it is in the code or Firebase configuration

Comment: Please post stacktrace.

Comment: Where can find the stack trace in logcat?

Comment: change your `onVerificationFailed` put this inside. `Log.d("vrification failed", e.getMessage());

Comment: It is showing this error:   This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]

Comment: I just created the project with com.example.verify and then put the jason file in app folder and turn on the phone verification thats all.....what else i need to do?

Comment: Your code is hiding a lot of useful information about problems. Whenever there is an exception, please always do what Ashish showed or (even better): `Log.e("TAG for searching/filtering","message describing the problem in your app", e)` (which will also log the stack trace).

Answer (score 2):

You have to put SHA-1 Key in your firebase Project.

To Retrieve SHA-1 Key by using Android Studio.

1. On Right side of Android Studio You will find **Gradle** Option.
2. Then Select **App** -> **Tasks** -> **android** -> Double Click on **signingReport**
3. It Will provide you SHA-1 Key in Build

[image: Gradle]

[image]

Now To Put SHA-1 Key inside your Firebase Project.

Open [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) then go to Project Setting.

At the bottom of Setting Page You will find your apps add FingerPrint in it.
[image]